# Finding duplicate records using cascading criteria, then combining into one record

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, data-cleaning, record-linkage

I am using MS SQL Server 2012, and have done simple querying and data loading, but not looping or case statements, or nested selects.  I am looking for some assistance to get me started on the approach.

We are in a project where we are combining the customer listing from multiple legacy systems.  I have a raw customer table in a staging database that contains records from those multiple sources.  We need to do the following before writing the final table to a data mart.  I would think that would be quite common scenario in the data cleansing/golden record world, but after much searching, have not been able to locate a similar post.

First, we need to find records that represent the same customer.  These records are coming from multiple sources so there could be more than 2 records that represent the same customer.  Each source uses a similar model.  The criteria that determines whether the record(s) represent the same customer changes in a cascading hierarchy depending on the values available.  The first criteria we want to use for a record is the DOB and SSN.  But if the SSN is missing, then the criteria for that row becomes the Last Name, First Name and DOB.  If both the SSN and the DOB are missing, then the duplicate test changes to last name + first name + another criteria field.  There are other criteria even after this if one of the names is missing.  And since records that represent the same customer may have different fields available, we would have to use the test that both records can use.  There may not be duplicate records if it turns out that a given customer only exists in one system.

2. Once duplicated records have been identified, we wish to then combine those records that represent a customer, so that we end up with 1 record representing the customer written to a new table, using the same fields.  Combining is done by comparing values of like fields.  If the SSN is missing from one source, but is available in another, then that SSN is used. If there are more than 2 records that represent a customer, and more than 1 has an SSN, and those SSN numbers are different, there is a heirarchy based on which system the record came from, and we want to write the SSN value from the system highest in the hierarchy.  This kind of logic would be applied to each field we need to examine.

I think the piece that is hardest for me to conceptualize is how do you store values of one record so that you can compare against one or more other records in the same table, do the actual compare logic, then write the "winning" value to a new table?  If I can get some help with that, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The basic requirements that you have outlines are fulfilled by this query

```
SELECT a.ID,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER( PARTITION BY DOB, SSN ) AS Match1,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER( PARTITION BY [Last Name], [First Name], DOB ) AS Match2,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER( PARTITION BY [Last Name], [First Name], [Another criteria] ) AS Match3
INTO #Matchmaking
FROM tCustStaging
```

What you will likely find though is that you will need to "prepare" (cleanse) your data first, that is ensure that it is all in the same format and remove "rubbish". A common problem may be phone numbers where various formats can be used e.g. '02 1234 1234', '0212341234', '+212341234' etc. Names may also have variations in spelling especially for Compound Names.

Another way to do matching, is to calculate matches on all fields individually

```
SELECT a.ID,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER( PARTITION BY SSN ) AS SSNMatch,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER( PARTITION BY DOB ) AS DOBMatch,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER( PARTITION BY LEFT( [Last Name], 10 ) ) AS LNMatch10,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER( PARTITION BY LEFT( [Last Name], 9 ) ) AS LNMatch9,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER( PARTITION BY LEFT( [Last Name], 9 ) ) AS LNMatch8,
    etc.
    DENSE_RANK() OVER( PARTITION BY LEFT( [Last Name], 3 ) ) AS LNMatch8,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER( PARTITION BY LEFT( [First Name], 10 ) ) AS FNMatch10,
    etc.
    DENSE_RANK() OVER( PARTITION BY [Other criteria1] ) AS OC1,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER( PARTITION BY [Other criteria2] ) AS OC2,
INTO #Matchmaking
FROM tCustStaging
```

You then create the strongest match (SSN, DOB). You can also experiment with various combinations of fields to see what you get.

```
-- You can play around with various combinations to see what results you get
SELECT c.*
FROM #Matchmaking AS a
    INNER JOIN #Matchmaking AS b ON a.SSNMatch = b.SSNMatch AND a.DOBMatch = b.DOBMatch AND a.LNMatch10 = b.LNMatch10
    INNER JOIN tCustStaging AS C ON a.ID = c.ID
```

After each iteration of matching you save the results.

You then keep relaxing the matching criteria, while carefully checking for false matches, until matching criteria is so weak that you no longer get useful results.

You will end up eventually with a set of results based on different strength of matching criteria.

In the end the number of "questionable matches" (where you are not sure if two customers are the same or not) would depend on the initial quality of data and the quality of it after "preparation". You would likely still have to analyse some data manually.